# Spark GraphX: how to insert just a node to a graph

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I know that in GraphX we can merge two graphs in order to update an existing network for example...
However, as a usual operation for updating a network is to insert into it a *single* node. 
How could one do such an updating operation in GraphX ?!
Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

Graphs are immutable, so you can't add a single node to an existing graph, but you can create a new graph based on the previous with the additional node added. Say you had a graph like this:

```
var graph: Graph[Int,Int] = ...
```

You could add a new node like this:

```
graph = Graph(
    graph.vertices.union(sc.parallelize(Array[(VertexId, Int)]((13L, 1)))),
    graph.edges,
    0
)
```